Scheduled tasks not launching in ECS using EC2
I have existing tasks that are scheduled to launch into a cluster that only supports Fargate. I created a new cluster that supports both Fargate and EC2, updated the task-definition to supported both launch-types, and then deleted and recreated the task schedule with updates to use the new cluster with an EC2 launch type. The task should've started automatically and immediately, but nothing happened. The ASG didn't show/register any activity.
I manually set the 'desired' count to (1) on the ASG, and bumped the minimum accordingly. The EC2 instance provisioned, but no tasks started (I have a tool that polls the API every couple of seconds). In retrospect, I might've checked the 'stopped' tasks as well as the events, but it doesn't seem like the ECS was communicating with the ASG, anyway.
I deleted and recreated the schedule with updated to use Fargate, once again, and it started as it should've.
Any suggestions what might be preventing ECS from communicating capacity requirements to the ASG (and maybe preventing it from dispatching the tasks there at well)?
I did see this, but I'm not getting anything actively failing. I'm actually using Terraform to drive these changes, and typically option conflicts will fail during deployment. Therefore, I'm somewhat dissuaded from thinking this might make a difference. I'm not able to reattempt the experiment at the moment and also already reverted much of the config that I required. Could this (launch_type vs default_capacity_provider_strategy) be related?
Thank you.
